# Can you add DocumentFields when using a Template?

Tags: docusignapi

**Preface**: It's my understanding that `DocumentFields` are [metadata on a document](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm) that are not specifically tied to a recipient (and will thus not be shown as Form Data and can be retrieved on the document level). If this is incorrect, let me know.

---

Is there anyway to define `DocumentFields` when using a template? The templates I am using will only ever contain one document. I'm currently creating the DocuSign requests using a combination of templates and uploaded documents. Here is a piece of code that shows the creation of a request using a template:

```
var compositeTemplate = new CompositeTemplate()
{
     ServerTemplates = new List<ServerTemplate>(),
     InlineTemplates = new List<InlineTemplate>()
};

var signer = new Signer()
{
     RecipientId = primaryRecipient.ID.ToString(),
     Name = "Full Name Here",
     RoleName = "Role 1", // Matches role on template
     Email = "Fakeemail@fakeemail.com",
};
InlineTemplate inlineTemplate = new InlineTemplate()
{
     Sequence = "1",
     Recipients = new Recipients()
     {
          Signers = new List<Signer>(),
          CarbonCopies = envelopeCarbonCopies // Set but not included here
     }
};

ServerTemplate serverTemplate = new ServerTemplate()
{
    Sequence = "1",
    TemplateId = documentConfigurations[i].TemplateId
};

compositeTemplate.ServerTemplates.Add(serverTemplate);

inlineTemplate.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
compositeTemplate.InlineTemplates.Add(inlineTemplate);
```

The request works and the template is used. However, `ServerTemplate` object doesn't allow me to specify `DocumentFields`, and I can't use the `Documents` property of the inline template since I'm using a template defined in DocuSign.

If I cannot specify `DocumentFields` on a template through the API, can you do this using the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the document field you want to set in the server Template are `static`, then you can follow below steps to add these static `documentfields` to Server Template and, when Envelope will be created using this Server Template then it will be available in the Envelope as well.

a. Using DS Web App, download the Server Template, it will download as JSON

b. Open the JSON in the text editor (like Notepad++), and go to
   `documents` node in the JSON, and add `documentFields` as shown below.

```
"documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "uri": "/envelopes/40365a36-ddba-4132-a553-40b4d087935b/documents/1",
        "name": "Test.pdf",
        "order": "1",
        "pages": "1",
        "documentBase64": "<PDFBytes>",
        "display": "inline",
        "includeInDownload": "true",
        "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
        "templateLocked": "false",
        "templateRequired": "false",
        "documentGroup": "content",
        "documentFields": [{
                "name": "s_businessDocType",
                "value": "TL"
        }]
    }]
```

c. Save this JSON and re-upload it on WEBApp, it will generate new templateId.

When you will use this Server Template in the envelope, then envelope will have the `documentFields` present in the serverTemplate.

**UPDATE:**

If documentFields are dynamic, then follow below steps:

a. Create Envelope in a draft status.

b. Call below endpoint to add documentFields to the document

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/fields
```

c. Once you have added the documentFields then change the envelope status to sent using below endpoint

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could do that. If the data is dynamic, are there any other valid approaches?

Comment: do you want to retrieve something at document level or at envelope level will also work?

Comment: I'd prefer to retrieve it at the document level. Essentially, I want to have a DocumentField that specifies that document's type, much like your example JSON.

Comment: Edited my answer for dynamic documentFields